# Error when trying to post a document to mongo with a numpy boolean object in it

Tags: python, numpy, pymongo, bson

The error I'm getting is:

`bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: False, of type: <class 'numpy.bool_'>`

The contents of the document (dictionary in this case) that I'm trying to send is shown below (its a screenshot from pycharm). I've annotated in blue what I think is the offending boolean objects.

Other than reaching and changing these boolean types from numpy.bool to just normal python bool, is there any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you remove these 2 bools and check again? Try it if this not for these 2 objects. If after removing again error occurs, try remove all bools and check again to make sure it's because of boolean fields.

Comment: Other than converting the unsupported values as you said, I don't think there is a better solution. Even if somehow you'll add support for those values in Mongo, you'll have to convert those again once you read from the DB.